# appending key value pair to existing dictionary values in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, append, key-value

I'm trying achieve below results. Where I can save multiple key values for multiple string items.

```swift
//dict["Setting1"] = ["key1":"val1"]
//dict["Setting1"] = ["key2":"val2"]
//dict["Setting2"] = ["key1":"val1"]
//dict["Setting2"] = ["key2":"val2"]
// and so on..
//or
//dict["Setting1"].append(["key2":"val2"]) // this doesn't work

//accessing dict["Settings1"]["key1"]    ..should give me val1

var dict = [String:[String:String]]()

var lst1 = ["key2":"val2"]
dict["one"] = ["key1":"val1"]

dict["one"]?.append(lst1)

print(dict)
```

gives me error

```
error: value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'append'
obj["one"]?.append(lst1)
~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `dict["one"]` returns a `[String: String]` (a.k.a. `Dictionary<String, String>`), which has no member (property, function, etc.) named `append`.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do here, but what if `dict["one"]` already has `"key2"`? Do you want the value in `lst1` to replace the value in `dict["one"]`?

Comment: I'm not a Swift expert but this looks like a [merge](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127169-merge).

Comment: @Sweeper If dict["one"] already has value it will overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `Dictionary` which doesn't have methods like `append(_:)`. `append(:_)` adds something to the *end* of an `Array`, but `Dictionaries` are unordered.

To add something to a `Dictionary`, you first define a key for it, and then assign it a value in the `Dictionary`

It'll look like this:

```swift
var dict = [String :[String: String]]()
var lst1 = ["key2": "val2"]
dict["one"] = ["key1": "val1"]
```

But you can't append to `dict["one"]`, because **it's not an array**, you can only overwrite it

```swift
dict["one"] = lst1
```

Comment: Ok Thank you Will. But do you see what I'm trying to achieve. If not with Dictionary or if dictionary with other combination what is the best way to achieve above?